# Symfony2 FOSRestBundle routing with parent parameter

Tags: php, symfony

I use FOSRESTBundle routing and I want to use **parent** parameter.

I've found this in this example http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/6-automatic-route-generation_multiple-restful-controllers.html#resource-collection

But in my case it doesn't work. When I want to show all my routes by `router:debug` command, Symfony returns me error:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
>     The routing file "/home/kamil/public_html/.../routing.yml" contains unsupported keys for "sbg_survey_survey": "parent". Expected one of: "resource", "type", "pre
>     fix", "pattern", "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults", "requirements", "options", "condition" in /home/kamil/public_html/.../routing.yml (which is be
>     ing imported from "/home/kamil/public_html/.../routing_dev.yml").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I've found solution. Yesterday when I was trying to use it I had some problems, but now it's working correctly.

It's necessary to put these routes to separated file and load this file from `app/config/routing.yml`

My files:

app/config/routing.yml:

```
kamil_blog:
    type: rest
    resource: "@KamilBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

src/Kamil/BlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml:

```
blog_category:
    resource: "@KamilBlogBundle/Controller/CategoryController.php"
    type:     rest

blog_post:
    resource: "@KamilBlogBundle/Controller/PostController.php"
    type:     rest
    parent:   blog_category
```

Comment: To clarify this, the important part is the `type:rest` in the app/config/routing.yml